# SQL Server 2005 Full Text Search - Enabled but no name?

Tags: sql-server

I'm working on a SQL Server 2005 -> 2008 upgrade. Full-text search seems to be a possible blocking point when doing an in-place upgrade.  Among the possible problems are having a catalog named with more than 120 characters.

I ran this query on my 2005 instance to find 7 databases in the instance I want to upgrade that have full text enabled:

```
select * from sys.databases
where is_fulltext_enabled = 1
order by name
```

Then on each of the 7 db's, I ran this to try to determine the name of the catalogs:

```
select * from sysfulltextcatalogs
```

None of the 7 returned any records in the sysfulltextcatalogs table. My question is:

**Is it possible to have full text search enabled, but have no actual catalog created?**

Comment: EDIT: added "on my 2005 instance" to clarify that my question concerns our 2005 instance of sql server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is absolutely possible to have full text enabled and no catalogs created. In fact in SQL 2008 all databases are always full-text enabled as per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403375(v=SQL.100).aspx

Comment: Ok thanks for your reply. You mentioned SQL 2008 so I want to clarify your answer. I am still in the planning phase and haven't yet installed anything 2008 yet. The queries I ran above are on the 2005 instance. Knowing that, would you still say 2005 could have it enabled but no actual catalog?

Comment: Yes that is the case on SQL 2005, databases can be full-text enabled but no catalogs created.

Comment: Thank you. I checked in the C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\FTData on the box and there are some xml files last modified over 2 years ago so that seems to confirm that there are no catalogs. You seem confident in your response so - marked as answered.